# Specify global tangle file for source code export in Org mode 8.x

Tags: org-babel

I want to specify a default output file for all my tangle exports. I'm using Org mode 8.x. (For Org mode ≥9.0, see [How to tangle all code blocks to a common file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/40721))

This works:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC js :tangle "../js/out_file.js"
console.log("hello from org mode");
#+END_SRC
** 
#+BEGIN_SRC js :tangle "../js/out_file.js"
console.log("hello from org mode 2");
#+END_SRC
```

However, I don't want to keep repeating "../js/out_file.js" on each block.

I've looked at these following two links, which seem to be asking essentially the same question:

[link 1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/how-to-specify-default-header-arguments-in-orgmode-code-blocks)

[link 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/using-org-babel-to-tangle-to-a-variable-file-name)

However, none of the recommendations work:  If I just have a SRC block with no tangle arg, I get either "Tangled 0 code blocks from dummy.org" or "Wrote ./org/dummy.org" (which is the default file name)

Here's my final code.  Currently, all the methods are uncommented, so it's possible they are interfering with each other, but I have tried each method in isolation to the same effect:

```
* Header

# method 1
:PROPERITES:
:tangle: "../out_file.js"
:END:

# method 2
#+TANGLE: "../js/out_file.js"

# method 3
#+BABEL: :tangle "../js/out_file.js" 

# method 4
#+PROPERTY: header-args+ :tangle  "../js/out_file.js" 

# method 5
#+PROPERTY: header-args :session *my_js_session* :results silent :tangle "../js/out_file.js" 

** some js source
#+BEGIN_SRC js
console.log("hello from org mode");
#+END_SRC
** 
#+BEGIN_SRC js 
console.log("hello from org mode 2");
#+END_SRC
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Do I have to somehow evaluate the properties before they take effect?

Are there any org commands I can issue to verify if the properties are properly set?

Comment: You've misspelled your first example, perhaps that it. I'm using a similiar method for my `init.org`, with `:header-args:emacs-lisp: :tangle ../.emacs` instead of `:tangle:`.

Comment: Use `#+PROPERTY: tangle "~/.path/file.js"`. Put the cursor on it and `C-c C-c` it should give you *Local setup has been refreshed* message in minibuffer. Tangle a file with `C-c C-v t` (*org-babel-tangle*). It works for sure, because that is how I generate my dotfiles ;)

Comment: Bingo.  That's it.  Thanks for mentioning the "C-c C-c" part.  That might have been the part I was missing all along.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tangle all code blocks to a common file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40721/how-to-tangle-all-code-blocks-to-a-common-file)

Comment: @mankoff Not everyone is using the latest version, so this question is still relevant. It just needs to be clarified so people know which version it applies to.

Comment: @Gilles agreed, but it would be nice to see it flagged as "Maybe Duplicate" and linked to that one. People can still read this if they want, but the more-correct (and more-correct-as-time-goes-on) answer should have a clearer link than the comment to the low-rated and un-accepted answer here.

Answer (score 8):

To set ‘tangle file’ globally we should use `#+PROPERTY: tangle "~/.path/to/file.extension"`.

Unfortunatelly, that change is not enough; we need to trigger a refresh. We put cursor on that line and press `C-c C-c` which gives *Local setup has been refreshed* message in a minibuffer (or in **Messages** buffer). We could also reopen file which applies new settings. `C-c C-c` is a binding for `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` — a ‘[swiss knife](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-very-busy-C_002dc-C_002dc-key.html)’ org-mode function which

> If the cursor is in one of the special #+KEYWORD lines, this
>     triggers scanning the buffer for these lines and updating the
>     information.

Now, when our changes are ready we can `C-c C-v t` (or `C-c C-v C-t`;
or `M-x org-babel-tangle`) to tangle our file.

We can read more about specifying header arguments (not only at global
level) at [org manual page](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-header-arguments.html#Using-header-arguments).

Comment: Note it does not work in org-mode v9 any more. Now it is `#+PROPERTY: header-args  :tangle "~/file/path"`