# How to tangle all code blocks to a common file

Tags: org-mode

I am planning to keep my `.emacs` file settings inside an org file which I can then tangle to a .emacs file. However, for every emacs-lisp block I don't want to have to type the redundant `:tangle .emacs` everytime.

e.g.

```
Description of flim-flam

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle .emacs
<flim-flam>
#+END_SRC

Description of foo-bar

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle .emacs
<foo-bar>
#+END_SRC
```

What must I include at the top of the Org document so that all code blocks (unless explicitly marked :tangle no) are automatically tangled into the same file say `.emacs`?

(This question applies to Org mode ≥9.0. For older versions, see [Specify global tangle file for source code export in Org mode 8.x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13191))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle .emacs`

You may need to `C-c C-c` on that line to invoke it after typing it, but in the future it should execute when the file is opened.

If you have multiple languages, you would set `:tangle yes` and then each code block would be tangled to the current file basename plus the appropriate language extension. I don't know how to tangle to a file named `yes`.

---

Manual section: [16.8 Extracting Source Code](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html)

How to have multiple `#+PROPERTY:` lines: [How to specify default header arguments in orgmode code blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/how-to-specify-default-header-arguments-in-orgmode-code-blocks)

Comment: :tangle yes  needed  in the PROPERTY args to works

Comment: works after I did a `C-c C-c` to refresh the local setup