# org-mode org-babel share a global variable across the file

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm a beginner org-mode user. Is there a way to remove baseUrl being duplicated in each block like the following one?

```
#+NAME: request-something
#+HEADER: :var baseUrl="http://localhost:3000"
#+HEADER: :var email="foo@bar.com"
#+BEGIN_SRC http 
POST ${baseUrl}/api/foo
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "${email}",
}
#+END_SRC
```

I've tried to extract it as

```
#+NAME: baseUrl
| http://localhost:3000 |
```

but keep getting "cannot resolve a template to values" ob-http error trying to read it in src block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK the following solution did the trick:

1. add

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :var baseUrl="http://localhost:3000"
```

2. restart org-mode

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> in my case while staying on that PROPERTY line

*Messages* buffer would output the following lines as a result:

```
>org-mode restarted
>Local setup has been refreshed
```

Take a look at this related question if you want to know more
[How to specify default header arguments in orgmode code blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/how-to-specify-default-header-arguments-in-orgmode-code-blocks)